# In TFS 2017, what is the limit of characters with a default value for a field?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I would like to include a default value to the description field of work item. Currently I could see only 255 characters as a limit in earlier versions of tfs. Is there a change in it or the limitation is carried in TFS 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limitation is carried in TFS2017, nothing changed in thie area.

> **value**
>
> Optional. Specifies the value to be copied into the field when value
>   is specified for the from attribute. Valid values consist of a string
>   of text that contains between 1 and 255 characters.
>
> The value to copy can be empty.

More details please refer this official documentation from  [Define a default value or copy a value to a field](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/define-default-copy-value-field)

Comment: Thanx Patrick. Do you have any idea on the following link [Workitem Template](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/productivity/work-item-template)

Comment: @dia It's a  tool  for team admin. A work item template lets you **pre-populate** values for your team's commonly used fields. Just  a GUI tool, it's also use the same mechanism and code in xml file. You could export the xml file of your work item to confirm this.